# Jquery- Show/hide image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

on clicking the checkbox , an image should be displayed for 5 seconds and then it should hide..

```
   $(".isActive").click(function() {

         var checkBox_id = $(this).attr("id");        // id of checkbox
         var div_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.display_image').attr("id");
         $("#"+div_id).empty().html('<img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'spinner.gif')}"/>');
```

Blah.....Blah...

How to make change in code so that image will be displayed only for 5 seconds and then hide the image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this after your code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#"+div_id).empty();
}, 5000);
```

or you could change the middle line for:

```
$('#'+div_id).find('img').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use delay():

```
$( function(){
    $('button').click( function(){
        $('.image').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WPDF9/

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
setTimeout("function name", 5000);
```

[further here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)